# How do I add an order by to server side code in my mvc View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I append to the first line `.OrderBy` and specify a property `OrderById`. I'm finding it confusing, i.e. Func & KeySelector etc.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.PaymentItemTotals)
{ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Line)%></td>
        <td><strong><%= String.Format("{0:C}", item.AmountTotal)%></strong></td>
        <td><%= String.Format("{0:C}", item.Amount)%></td>
        <td><%= String.Format("{0:C}", item.AmountIndex)%></td>
    </tr>                    
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in Model.PaymentItemTotals
    .OrderBy(paymentItemTotal => paymentItemTotal.OrderById))
```

But consider doing this ordering either in your Model or Controller to make your view as stupid as possible.

Comment: Not sure I agree.  I would consider display order to be a view-level decision, not  Model or Controller level.

Comment: @Robaticus: It is a hard call, but in this case I like to think of it in a different way. If there was another View, maybe using the new binding style instead of the old ASP.NET way, or just simply a View for a phone, they would all have to sort the data. But if you pass in the IOrderedEnumerable, all the Views would just have to display it.

Comment: I can see it both ways.  Thanks for your insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 collection.OrderBy(o => o.FieldToOrderBy)
```

You may order on the controller before you pass it to the view.